# Cannot initialize remote git repository from local repository

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to initialize a local project as a new repository on Github, and am running into a problem when running the `git add .` command. My project has the following file structure (which I think is the source of the problem, but am not sure why):

`PROJECT_NAME` (top level folder)

- `PROJECT_NAME_OLD` (subfolder with project files inside)
- `PROJECT_NAME_UPDATED` (subfolder with other project files inside)

Not sure what the exact file structure terminology is, but here is the process I have used so far to try and initialize the project with a remote repository:

1. From terminal, change directory into `PROJECT_NAME` and run `git init` (successful)
2. Run `git add .` (failed with the following error: `'PROJECT_NAME/' does not have a commit checked out,  fatal: adding files failed`)
3. Run `git remote add origin git@github.com:unique_url` (successful)
4. Run `git push -u origin master` (failed with the following error: `error: src refspec master does not match any`)

When trying to run the `git commit -m"message"` command, I received a message saying that the files for `PROJECT_NAME_OLD/` and `PROJECT_NAME_UPDATED/` were untracked as well as a new file `.DS_STORE`, but I'm not sure what this means or how to fix it?

I am wondering what I'm doing wrong here, and if there is a way for me to undo any incorrect steps I've taken and initialize this repository with the file structure that I already have in place?

Comment: can you tell us the output of `git branch`?

Comment: @Y4glory, when I run `git branch` in the `PROJECT_NAME` directory, the system opens up a text file using VIM or a similar editor? No other messages.

Comment: Hey, that's weird. Can you tell me the output of  `git remote -v` and could you try checking out to master like so `git checkout master` or if that does not work `git checkout -B master`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the branch. Take the following steps:-

1. Check if there is the creation of .git file after doing `git init`.
2. Check the branch using `git branch` and  a look if you are at
   the master branch.
3. Then check the status of the files using `git status` it will show if any file is changed.
4. Then do `git add individual file` or `git add .` as you wish.
5. Then commit the changes.
6. And then push.

If `git add .` fails there is a possibility that the next steps will also fail.And also check `git remote -v` if your origin branch is at the remote.

Comment: I followed these steps and while `git add .` did not work, adding the individual files by name did work - thank you for the help.

Comment: "and a look if you are at the master branch" - How? I entered "git branch" and I get nothing.